# Django forms: add a custom label

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form that contains a lot of widget.

To summarize, a widget = a label + an input.

I have a big loop where I display my fields like this:

```
{% if field.label %}
    <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" sr-only">{{ field.label }}
    </label>
{% endif %}
{{ field }}
```

My client want me to add a special text **between** two fields.

He wants something like:

- label "town" -> input
- *specific* label: "choose your date:"
- label "date start" -> input
- label "date end" -> input

I'm looking for a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the [`help_text`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#help-text) attribute of a field is generally for. Think, for example, of a small caption that says "Two-letter abbreviation" below an input for a state/province.

```
...
{{ field }}
{% if field.help_text %}<div class='styleme'>{{ field.help_text }}</div>{% endif %}
```

Of course, you could always render each field individually if need be. Cleaner (if you have many fields) - test for when a certain field is in the loop.

```
{% if field.label == "A Certain Field" %}
    <div>Some text here</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The second option = hard coded is less good, but very good idea I'll try the #1!